# Batch file to written the log file that operation performed the script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I created a batch file for deleting the .txt files in the directory, and I should know which files it deleted. For that, I have written a log file code, but unfortunately, the log file is not creating the files deleted information.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%f in (*.txt) do (DEL %%f)

for /d %%a in (D:\link\dink\) do del /s "%%a\*.txt"



SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
set month=%%j
set day=%%k
set year=%%l
)
set periodid=%year%%month%%day%


SET LOGLOC=D:\link\dink\Deleted_Txt_Log_!periodid!.txt

 
CD /D D:\link\dink\
ECHO ************************************************** >>%LOGLOC%
ECHO Log entry for %DATE% %time% >>%LOGLOC%
ECHO. >>%LOGLOC%
ECHO Pull start time %date% %time% >> %LOGLOC%
ECHO ************************************************** >>%LOGLOC%
```

Comment: What part of your code is supposed to list the files that were deleted? Right now, the only thing that you're sending to the `%LOGLOC%` log are asterisks and timestamps. If you want to log that a deletion happened, you need to actually include that in the script somewhere.

Comment: The .txt files that I am deleting the file names it has to list in the Log file. Can you please modify the above script?

Comment: Why use ```for %%f in (*.txt) do (DEL %%f)``` instead of ```Del /Q *.txt```? And why the incorrect ```for /d %%a in (D:\link\dink\) do del /s "%%a\*.txt"``` instead of ```Del /Q /S "D:\link\dlink\*.txt"```? If the latter is because you need to keep files with extensions beginning with `.txt` in `D:\link\dlink`, but not its subdirectories, then change `(D:\link\dink\)` to `(D:\link\dink\*)`.

Comment: I can consider all the above, but my question is that storing the deleted files' names must be listed in the log file. The script I provided creates the log file but does not keep the information about which files were deleted. Can someone help me with it?